# JQuery - HTML to PDF doesn't work in IE (from C# asmx webservice)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, pdf

I have created a simple C# asmx service to convert HTML to a working PDF (I am using the free NReco C# library).

It works fabulously well in Firefox and Chrome but IE will not download the file. Can somebody take a look at my JavaScript?

Here is a very hacky JSFiddle that shows my JavaScript code:
[jsfiddle_link](http://jsfiddle.net/fictus/yjq2gz0o/)

Here is my C# asmx code:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "<div style=\"font-weight:bold;\">Passing Parameters to Format your PDF file</div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:20px;border:1px solid black;background-color:#FFFFD9;display:inline-block;\"><b>orientation</b> - \"sets the page orientation\"</div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:40px;\"><table style=\"border-collapse:collapse;\"><tr><td style=\"background-color:gray;color:white;\">usage:</td><td style=\"padding-left:10px;\">\\\"orientation\\\":\\\"portrait\\\"<br/>OR<br/>\\\"orientation\\\":\\\"landscape\\\"</td></tr></table></div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:20px;border:1px solid black;background-color:#FFFFD9;display:inline-block;\"><b>height</b> - \"sets the page height (you can use in, cm, mm or px)\"</div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:40px;\"><table style=\"border-collapse:collapse;\"><tr><td style=\"background-color:gray;color:white;\">usage:</td><td style=\"padding-left:10px;\">\\\"height\\\":\\\"4in\\\"</td></tr></table></div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:20px;border:1px solid black;background-color:#FFFFD9;display:inline-block;\"><b>width</b> - \"sets the page width (you can use in, cm, mm or px)\"</div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:40px;\"><table style=\"border-collapse:collapse;\"><tr><td style=\"background-color:gray;color:white;\">usage:</td><td style=\"padding-left:10px;\">\\\"width\\\":\\\"6in\\\"</td></tr></table></div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:20px;border:1px solid black;background-color:#FFFFD9;display:inline-block;\"><b>smartshrink</b> - \"tries to shrink your html code so that it can all fit in one page\"</div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:40px;\"><table style=\"border-collapse:collapse;\"><tr><td style=\"background-color:gray;color:white;\">usage:</td><td style=\"padding-left:10px;\">\\\"smartshrink\\\":\\\"true\\\"</td></tr></table></div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:20px;border:1px solid black;background-color:#FFFFD9;display:inline-block;\"><b>title</b> - \"embeds details in the file-details-title section of the pdf file\"</div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:40px;\"><table style=\"border-collapse:collapse;\"><tr><td style=\"background-color:gray;color:white;\">usage:</td><td style=\"padding-left:10px;\">\\\"title\\\":\\\"This PDF was created in Prince Manufacturing\\\"</td></tr></table></div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:20px;border:1px solid black;background-color:#FFFFD9;display:inline-block;\"><b>removemargins</b> - \"by default, pdf docs are created with a marin of 1in on all sides. This sets all margins to 0\"</div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:40px;\"><table style=\"border-collapse:collapse;\"><tr><td style=\"background-color:gray;color:white;\">usage:</td><td style=\"padding-left:10px;\">\\\"removemargins\\\":\\\"true\\\"</td></tr></table></div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:20px;border:1px solid black;background-color:#FFFFD9;display:inline-block;\"><b>marginright | marginleft | margintop | marginbottom</b> - \"Sets given margin size (in pixels)\"</div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:40px;\"><table style=\"border-collapse:collapse;\"><tr><td style=\"background-color:gray;color:white;\">usage:</td><td style=\"padding-left:10px;\">\\\"marginleft\\\":\\\"30\\\"</td></tr></table></div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:20px;border:1px solid black;background-color:#FFFFD9;display:inline-block;\"><b>includepagenumbers</b> - \"adds a footer to each pdf page displaying 'Page x of y'\"</div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:40px;\"><table style=\"border-collapse:collapse;\"><tr><td style=\"background-color:gray;color:white;\">usage:</td><td style=\"padding-left:10px;\">\\\"includepagenumbers\\\":\\\"true\\\"</td></tr></table></div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:20px;border:1px solid black;background-color:#FFFFD9;display:inline-block;\"><b>rotate</b> - \"rotates all PDF pages to the specified degrees\"</div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:40px;\"><table style=\"border-collapse:collapse;\"><tr><td style=\"background-color:gray;color:white;\">usage:</td><td style=\"padding-left:10px;\">(Acceptable degrees: -90 90 180)<br/><br/>\\\"rotate\\\":\\\"90\\\"</td></tr></table></div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:20px;border:1px solid black;background-color:#FFFFD9;display:inline-block;\"><b>customeargs</b> - \"allows you to manually add any of the available wkhtml parameters\"</div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:40px;\"><table style=\"border-collapse:collapse;\"><tr><td style=\"background-color:gray;color:white;\">usage:</td><td style=\"padding-left:10px;\">(for all available parameters please refer to http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html)<br/><br/>\\\"customeargs\\\":\\\"--footer-right `My PDF is Cool!`\\\"</td></tr></table></div>" +
            "<div style=\"padding:8px;margin-left:20px;background-color:yellow;display:inline-block;border:1px solid orange;\">In your C# code pass the parameters in a JSON string this way:<br/><br/>\"{\\\"orientation\\\":\\\"landscape\\\",\\\"height\\\":\\\"2in\\\",\\\"width\\\":\\\"3in\\\",\\\"smartshrink\\\":\\\"false\\\",\\\"removemargins\\\":\\\"true\\\"}\"</div>" +
            "")]
        public void ConvertHTMLtoPDFJS(int entryType, string sessionID, string inHTML, string properties, string FileNamex)
        {
            /* Lets do a little house cleaning first; we will delete any junk HTML parts older than one day */
            using (MySqlConnection myConnectionX = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["valleEvicore"].ConnectionString.ToString()))
            {
                myConnectionX.Open();
                MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand("spMobileServices_deleteOldHTMLparts", myConnectionX);
                myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            /******************************/

            if (entryType == 0)
            {
                using (MySqlConnection myConnectionX = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["valleEvicore"].ConnectionString.ToString()))
                {
                    myConnectionX.Open();
                    MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand("spMobileServices_insertHTMLpart", myConnectionX);
                    myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_sessionid", sessionID);
                    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_htmlpart", inHTML);

                    myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("{\"error\":\"0\",\"pdfRes\":\"0\"}");
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.parent.postMessage(\"next\", \"*\");</script>");
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

                //HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
                //HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                DataTable tblResults = new DataTable();
                StringBuilder htmlSB = new StringBuilder();

                using (MySqlConnection myConnectionX = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["valleEvicore"].ConnectionString.ToString()))
                {
                    myConnectionX.Open();
                    MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand("spMobileServices_getHTMLpartsBySessionID", myConnectionX);
                    myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_sessionid", sessionID);

                    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(myCmd);
                    adapter.Fill(tblResults);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < tblResults.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    htmlSB.Append(System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(tblResults.Rows[i][2].ToString()));
                }

                inHTML = htmlSB.ToString();

                using (MySqlConnection myConnectionX = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["valleEvicore"].ConnectionString.ToString()))
                {
                    myConnectionX.Open();
                    MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand("spMobileServices_deleteHTMLparts", myConnectionX);
                    myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_sessionid", sessionID);

                    myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter pdfConv = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
                pdfConv.PdfToolPath = @"C:\PDFTools\";

                properties = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(properties).Trim();
                string[] finRotate = { "false", "" };

                try
                {
                    if (properties.Trim() == "none" || properties.Trim() == "")
                    {
                        //pdfConv.CustomWkHtmlArgs = "-O portrait";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        try
                        {
                            Dictionary<string, string> finJSON = jsonParse(properties.ToLower());

                            if (finJSON.ContainsKey("orientation"))
                            {
                                if (finJSON["orientation"] == "portrait")
                                {
                                    sb.Append(" -O portrait");
                                }
                                else if (finJSON["orientation"] == "landscape")
                                {
                                    sb.Append(" -O landscape");
                                }
                            }
                            if (finJSON.ContainsKey("smartshrink"))
                            {
                                if (finJSON["smartshrink"] == "false")
                                {
                                    sb.Append(" --disable-smart-shrinking");
                                }
                            }
                            if (finJSON.ContainsKey("title"))
                            {
                                sb.Append(" --title \"" + finJSON["title"] + "\"");
                            }
                            if (finJSON.ContainsKey("removemargins"))
                            {
                                if (finJSON["removemargins"] == "true")
                                {
                                    //if (smartShrink == false)
                                    //{
                                    //    sb.Append(" --margin-right 0 --margin-top 1 --margin-bottom 0 --margin-left 1");
                                    //}
                                    //else
                                    //{
                                    //    sb.Append(" --margin-right 0 --margin-top 0 --margin-bottom 0 --margin-left 0");
                                    //}
                                    sb.Append(" --margin-right 0 --margin-top 0 --margin-bottom 0 --margin-left 0");
                                }
                            }
                            if (finJSON.ContainsKey("marginright"))
                            {
                                sb.Append(" --margin-right " + finJSON["marginright"]);
                            }
                            if (finJSON.ContainsKey("marginleft"))
                            {
                                sb.Append(" --margin-left " + finJSON["marginleft"]);
                            }
                            if (finJSON.ContainsKey("margintop"))
                            {
                                sb.Append(" --margin-top " + finJSON["margintop"]);
                            }
                            if (finJSON.ContainsKey("marginbottom"))
                            {
                                sb.Append(" --margin-bottom " + finJSON["marginbottom"]);
                            }
                            if (finJSON.ContainsKey("width"))
                            {
                                sb.Append(" --page-width " + finJSON["width"]);
                            }
                            if (finJSON.ContainsKey("height"))
                            {
                                sb.Append(" --page-height " + finJSON["height"]);
                            }
                            if (finJSON.ContainsKey("includepagenumbers"))
                            {
                                if (finJSON["includepagenumbers"] == "true")
                                {
                                    sb.Append(" --footer-right \"Page [page] of [toPage]\"");
                                }
                                //pdfConv.CustomWkHtmlArgs = "--footer-right \"Page [page] of [toPage]\"";
                            }
                            if (finJSON.ContainsKey("customeargs"))
                            {
                                sb.Append(" " + finJSON["customeargs"].ToString().Replace("`", "\""));
                            }
                            if (finJSON.ContainsKey("rotate"))
                            {
                                finRotate[0] = "true";
                                finRotate[1] = finJSON["rotate"];
                            }

                            if (sb.ToString().Trim() == "")
                            {
                                //pdfConv.CustomWkHtmlArgs = "-O portrait";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                pdfConv.CustomWkHtmlArgs = sb.ToString().Trim();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            //pdfConv.CustomWkHtmlArgs = "-O portrait";
                        }
                    }

                    if (finRotate[0] == "true")
                    {
                        var pdfBytes = pdfConv.GeneratePdf(inHTML.ToString().Replace("⌐", "<").Replace("¬", ">"));
                        string tmpRfile = @"C:\PDFTools\rotate_" + Get8Digits() + ".pdf";
                        File.WriteAllBytes(tmpRfile, pdfBytes.ToArray());
                        rotatePDF(finRotate[1], tmpRfile);

                        FileStream fs = new FileStream(tmpRfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                        byte[] filebytes = new byte[fs.Length];
                        fs.Read(filebytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
                        string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(filebytes, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);

                        fs.Close();

                        bool fileDead = false;
                        while (fileDead == false)
                        {
                            fileDead = deletePDFFile(tmpRfile);
                        }

                        var buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
                        string whatI = "pdf";
                        bool showInline = false;

                        if (buffer != null)
                        {
                            if (whatI == "pdf")
                            {
                                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
                            }
                            else if (whatI == "doc")
                            {
                                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "Application/msword";
                            }
                            else if (whatI == "xls")
                            {
                                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "Application/x-msexcel";
                            }
                            else if (whatI == "dwf")
                            {
                                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "drawing/x-dwf";
                            }

                            string dispositionType = "";
                            if (showInline == true)
                            {
                                dispositionType = "inline;";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                dispositionType = "attachment;";
                            }

                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                            //Response.ContentType = "drawing/x-dwf";
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", dispositionType + " filename=" + FileNamex);
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();

                            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Clear();
                            //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";                            
                            //HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("200", "Content-Type=application/json");
                            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("{\"status\":\"OK\"}");
                            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "200 OK";
                            //HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;

                            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

                            //HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
                            //HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
                        }

                        //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
                        //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
                        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">var myBase64PDF=\"" + encodedData + "\";window.parent.postMessage(myBase64PDF, \"*\");</script>");
                        //HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //var pdfBytes = pdfConv.GeneratePdf(System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(inHTML.ToString()));

                        var buffer = pdfConv.GeneratePdf(inHTML.ToString().Replace("⌐", "<").Replace("¬", ">"));
                        string whatI = "pdf";
                        bool showInline = false;

                        if (buffer != null)
                        {
                            if (whatI == "pdf")
                            {
                                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
                            }
                            else if (whatI == "doc")
                            {
                                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "Application/msword";
                            }
                            else if (whatI == "xls")
                            {
                                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "Application/x-msexcel";
                            }
                            else if (whatI == "dwf")
                            {
                                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "drawing/x-dwf";
                            }

                            string dispositionType = "";
                            if (showInline == true)
                            {
                                dispositionType = "inline;";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                dispositionType = "attachment;";
                            }

                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                            //Response.ContentType = "drawing/x-dwf";
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", dispositionType + " filename=" + FileNamex);
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();

                            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Clear();
                            //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                            //HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("200", "Content-Type=application/json");
                            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("{\"status\":\"OK\"}");
                            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "200 OK";
                            //HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;

                            //HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

                            //HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
                            //HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
                        }

                        //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
                        //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
                        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">var myBase64PDF=\"" + System.Convert.ToBase64String(buffer) + "\";window.parent.postMessage(myBase64PDF, \"*\");</script>");
                        //HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                    }
                }
                //catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException err)
                //{
                //    System.Threading.Thread.ResetAbort();
                //}
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (!ex.Message.ToString().Contains("Thread was being aborted"))
                    {
                        //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
                        //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/json";
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("{\"error\":\"1\", \"errorCode\":" + jss.Serialize(ex.Message.ToString()) + "}");
                        //HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

                        //HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;
                        //HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void rotatePDF(string degrees, string xFileName)
        {
            try
            {
                FileInfo rFile = new FileInfo(xFileName);
                string tempPDFfile = @"C:\PDFTools\rotate_" + Get8Digits() + "_" + rFile.Name;
                System.IO.File.Move(xFileName, tempPDFfile);

                if (degrees == "-90")
                {
                    degrees = "1-endL";
                }
                else if (degrees == "90")
                {
                    degrees = "1-endR";
                }
                else if (degrees == "180")
                {
                    degrees = "1-endS";
                }

                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();

                StreamWriter sw = process.StandardInput;

                if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("\"" + @"C:\PDFTools\pdftk.exe" + "\" \"" + tempPDFfile + "\" cat " + degrees + " output \"" + xFileName + "\" dont_ask");

                        //Writing the Command to Exit the CMD  
                        sw.WriteLine("exit");
                    }
                    catch (Exception exxxz)
                    {
                        throw exxxz;
                    }
                }

                process.WaitForExit();

                bool fileDead = false;
                while (fileDead == false)
                {
                    fileDead = deletePDFFile(tempPDFfile);
                    //Application.DoEvents();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private bool deletePDFFile(string xFile)
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(xFile))
            {
                try
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(xFile);
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: verify the mime type http header. If the file is being generated and is being downloaded from one browser and not another, it's probably not in the actual code that generates the pdf that the problem resides. You can also look at the difference between the request IE makes vs Firefox. Check your server logs to verify the request is actually being processed.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddle-farting with this issue for days it occurred to me - what if JSFiddle was causing my issue?

I decided to port my example to a live aspx page and it works perfectly in IE!